# Modify Django "Select Form" Icon

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am making a Django app, and I am using Django's form.ChoiceFields to make a form!

```
brand = forms.ChoiceField(
    label="Marca:",
    choices=[('', 'Selecionar marca')] + [(brand.id, brand.name) for brand in models.Brand.objects.all()],
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'brand', 'onchange': 'filterModels()', 'class': 'select'})
)
```

So this is the form element that I get (with a background color), but I want to change the icon pointing up and down in the right but I cannot figure how to do it.

[image]

I already tried to do it by adding an icon form FontAwesome but the problem is that when I do so, when I click on the icon the form does not open, so it can confuse the users :( I tried adding javascript codes by using implementing the click() function when clicking on the icon but it did not give me any results.

[image]

So is there a way to do this by simply replacing Django's "Select Form" default arrow icon?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this for anyone in the future! In the end I ended up styling a div the same way as the form and sending it to the back using z-index. Then I added transparency on the form using linear-gradient so that only the blue portion would be totally transparent! If you do this be careful to use positions correctly. Hope this helps anyone in the future :)

Comment: Great you posted the answer, it could be worthy to add the code as well